# How to upgrade GitLab CE from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gitlab, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, gitlab-ce

Can someone explain me how I can upgrade a running gitlab CE on Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04?

I could not find any relevant documentation for this upgrade path

It is clear to upgrade ubuntu with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But what is needed to tell rerun the setup/upgrade on gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade your Ubuntu Version from 16.04 to 18.04, you also need to alter the repository path for debian packages provided by GitLab Inc.

If you inspect the [installation/configuration script](https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh) available on GitLab.com, you will see that there should be a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which contains `gitlab` in its filename.

Simply replace its content with the following lines:

```
deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

You are now able to upgrade GitLab using the new package repository for your upgraded Ubuntu System:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean update Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 then here's the steps:
I did that a couple of days ago.

```
lsb_release -a # This is just to check the. Ubuntu version 
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This will make sure that you have all the packages updated. The upgrade will not start if you don't have them upgraded.

Then for the actual upgrade

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

### NOTE

1 - The above command might fail because "you have to upgrade all the packages before" please inspect the output of `sudo apt upgrade` maybe you have a dependency issue & not all the packages are upgraded

2- Please make sure you have all your data backed up before doing the upgrade. I'm assuming that you doing the upgrade via SSH which may be troublesome.
For me, the upgrade got stuck while trying to update the openSSH config files. What I did is that I closed the current SSH session ( tmux ) opened a new session & rebooted the server.

After the server is rebooted

```
lsb_release -a
```

Should show

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: this is the basic ubuntu upgrade. This is clear but...
gitlab needs also a form of upgrade and I do not get what is needed on gitlab